# Joomla 3: Execution jquery function

Tags: jquery, joomla3.0

I am a beginner in Javascript, I use a template which uses jquery to resize the height of a column. The javascript code does work well in a simple index.html page however when I use that in joomla 3 the jQuery functions do not execute. 
So I added:

- 'jQuery.noConflict();'
- replace all the $ into jQuery

and still the height do not resize.

Below the code:

```
    jQuery.noConflict();
// JavaScript Document
jQuery(window).load(function () {



    var winWidth = jQuery(window).width()

            if (winWidth > 767){

                // To ensure that the sidebar sticks to the bottom of the page
                // we calculate the height of the tallest object and match the
                // sidebar to it.

                var height1 = jQuery('.eightcol').height()
                var height2 = jQuery('html').height()
                var height3 = jQuery("#sidebar-container").height()
                var height4 = jQuery(window).height()

                /*  Tab Shortcode Fix
                    Because all tabbed content loads stacked this throws off
                    the height of the .eightcol and html elements so we need to subtract 
                    the extra height added by the stacked tabbed content. Once we have that
                    we can reset the hight values of html and .eightcol correctly. We will
                    need to figure out the tallest of all the tabbed content elements
                    and add that back into the total height of .eightcol and html

                    ONLY do this if we are using the tab shortcode.
                */
                if (jQuery('.tabcontent').length) {
                    var max = 0;
                    var numtotal = 0;
                    // Loop through all .tabcontent classes and get the tallest tab.
                    jQuery('.tabcontent').each(function(){
                        var num = jQuery(this).height()
                        // Track total height of all tabs so we can subtract later
                        numtotal = numtotal + num;
                        if(num > max)
                        {
                           max = num;
                        }
                    });

                    // Substract the total height of all .tabcontent from .eightcol and html
                    // then add in only the lattest .tabcontent.
                    height1 = height1 - numtotal;
                    height1 = height1 + max;

                    height2 = height2 - numtotal;
                    height2 = height2 + max;

                };



                // Function to get the Max value in Array
                Array.max = function( array ){
                return Math.max.apply( Math, array );
                };

                var maxheight = Array.max([height1,height2,height3,height4])


                if (height3 < maxheight) {
                    //jQuery("#sidebar").height(maxheight)
                    jQuery("#sidebar").css('height', maxheight + 'px');
                }

            }else{
                jQuery("#sidebar").css("height","auto")
            }   

    jQuery(window).resize(function() {

            var winWidth = jQuery(window).width()

            if (winWidth > 767){

                var height1 = jQuery('.eightcol').height()
                var height2 = jQuery('html').height()
                var height3 = jQuery("#sidebar-container").height()
                var height4 = jQuery(window).height()




                // Function to get the Max value in Array
                Array.max = function( array ){
                return Math.max.apply( Math, array );
                };

                var maxheight = Array.max([height1,height2,height3,height4])

                //console&&console.log('maxheight ' + maxheight);

                if (height3 < maxheight) {
                    jQuery("#sidebar").css('height', maxheight + 'px');
                }
            }else{
                    jQuery("#sidebar").css("height","auto")
            }

       });

}); 

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            var height3 = jQuery("#sidebar-container").height()
        });
```

Am I doing it properly? Do you have any idea why it does not work?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to achieve? I will say i'm spoiled by the Protostar template with Twitter Bootstrap implementation.  I strongly recommend that you start there, look closely at it index.php page and look at it graphical template.  Finally do the dynamic test and narrow up your browser window, see where the div's fall.  Check out your site on a couple of different smart phones.  Etc...  Again where are you going with the project?

Note:  There are some free Joomla 3 dynamic templates out there with crazy unnecessary complexity built in.  Its my belief they are done that way to catch the unsuspecting to the point where the only way out is to hire the template developer to bail you out.  No names mentioned.  Its similiar to the barb on a fish hook concept of got ya!  That's their business model.

Recommendation:  Start with Protostar, redesign the div's, learn how to use .less to create your style sheets and move this one along...